# When attempting to install Windows 10 64 bit GUI: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platforms plugin "windows"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platforms plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

And a runtime error
Program: C:\Users\Ric\desktop\monero-gui-x64-v0.10.3.1 -1\monero-wallet-gui.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Any help?

Comment: Unrelated (though it could fix your problem), but 0.10.3.1 is now obsolete, and you should use (as of now) 0.11.0.0. This might fix your problem as a side effect too, since there were Qt changes.

Answer (score 2):

there seems to be a space in the path where it is stored. move it to a place without spaces and try again

Comment: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platforms plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

And a runtime error Program: C:\Users\Ric\desktop\monero-gui-x64-v0.10.3.1\monero-wallet-gui.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

I redownloaded and reinstalled. Same error

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but have you tried the `start-low-graphics-mode.bat` file to start the GUI?